# Japanese characters in a latex \section{} cause an error

Tags: unicode, latex, cjk

I am working on getting Japanese documents created with latex. I have installed the latest version of texlive-2008 which includes CJK.

In my document I have the following:

```
\documentclass{class}
\usepackage{CJK}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{min}
\title{[Japanese Characters here 1]}
\maketitle
\section{[Japanese Characters here 2]}
[Japanese Characters here 3]
\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

In the above code there are 3 locations Japanese characters are used.

1 + 3 work fine whereas 2, which contains Japanese characters in a \section{} fails with the following error.

```
! Argument of \@sect has an extra }.
```

After some research it turns out this error manifests when you’ve put a fragile command inside a moving argument. A moving argument because section can be moved to a contents page for example.

Does anyone know how to get this to work and why latex thinks Japanese characters are "fragile".

Comment: As a hack I have changed \section{[JP]} to \section[]{[JP]}

This works in some documents that don't have contents pages as the square brackets denote the movable section. For most documents I still need to be able to use them normally to generate contents and indexs etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry to post this as an answer rather than a comment to your answer; I don't have enough rep yet to comment. (EDIT: Now I have enough rep to comment, but I'm not sorry anymore. Thanks Will.)

Your solution of replacing

```
\section{[Japanese Text]}
```

with

```
\section{\texorpdfstring{[Japanese Text]}{}}
```

suggests that you're using the `hyperref` package. When you use the `hyperref` package, *any* sort of not-totally-boring text (e.g. math) within `\section` causes a problem because `\section` is having trouble generating pdf bookmarks. `\texorpdfstring` allows you to specify how you want the section title to appear in the pdf bookmark. For example, I might write

```
\section{Calculation of \texorpdfstring{$H_2(\mathcal{X})$}{H\_2(X)}}
```

if I want the section title to be "Calculation of $H_2(\mathcal{X})$" but I want the pdf bookmark to be "Calculation of H_2(X)".

Comment: This is more appropriate as an answer, don't be sorry!

Answer (score 3):

You should probably use xetex/xelatex, as it has been created to support unicode. The change is sometimes not easy for already existing documents, though. (xelatex should be included in texlive, it is just different executable to call -- this is how it is done in Debian).

Comment: I was going to suggest xelatex or xetex as well. you need this in your preamble: 
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
\usepackage{fontspec} % Font selection for XeLaTeX; see fontspec.pdf for documentation
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text} % to support TeX conventions like ``---''
\usepackage{xunicode} % Unicode support for LaTeX character names (accents, European chars, etc)
\usepackage{xltxtra} % Extra customizations for XeLaTeX

\setmainfont{Charis SIL} 
%\setsansfont{Deja Vu Sans}
%\setmonofont{Deja Vu Mono}

Comment: As an additional note that may [hopefully] help others, once I switched to `xelatex` to build PDFs that included ja-JP unicode characters, I had to explicitly specify default fonts that had hiragana/katakana/Kanji characters, whereas this was not something I had to do with vanilla `latex`+`dvipdf`. However, with the latter I wasn't able to include them in section and chapter headings at all when I used a TOC. A tradeoff either way, but explicitly defining some of these things in the preamble as suggested by @Mica is likely more preferable for most anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to get this working now!

Using Latex and CJK as before.

```
\section{[Japanese Text]}
```

was replaced with

```
\section{\texorpdfstring{[Japanese Text]}{}}
```

Now the contents pages and section titles work and update fine.